# Washington DC odd tour request issue

Tags: tours, event-based-effects, washington-dc

I recently submitted some Washington DC tour requests to a member of congress that just lost their election. My trip is scheduled for before they leave office. Could the election results affect my chances of getting the tours? Should I talk to a different congress person as a back up or will the office continue to conduct business as usual until the results take effect?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The new Congress meets on January 3, 2017 and, although there will be transition activities, tours should go ahead as scheduled. However, it would be wise to contact your representative's office for confirmation, particularly if you have not received a tour date. With the approaching holidays, you might want to call or email your local, in-state office for a more immediate response.